# mappedBy Hibernate error only when deployed to Heroku

Tags: java, hibernate, heroku

I have a simple Java project using Hibernate, ClearDB MySQL and Heroku. When I run locally (Tomcat 9.0) via Eclipse, everything works (including retrieval of a persisted object), but once I deploy to Heroku, I receive the Hibernate "mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property" on one of my OneToMany joins.

Here is the error, with stack trace, I get when deployed (as caught and printed by my Main.java HttpServlet):

```
[PersistenceUnit: coloradotaghunter_manager] Unable to build Hibernate 
SessionFactory
Caused by...
mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.coloradotaghunter.Tag.gmu in com.coloradotaghunter.Gmu.tags
org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)
org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860)
org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
com.coloradotaghunter.TagHunterService.<init>(TagHunterService.java:30)
Main.doGet(Main.java:23)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And here are the involved Gmu (parent) and Tag (children) objects:

Gmu.java

```
/**
 * Gmu generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "gmu", catalog = "heroku_74dfffe65503eee")
public class Gmu implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
//  private static final long serialVersionUID = -501255736919935566L;
    private int gmuNbr;
    private String regionCode;
    private Set<HarvestEstimate> harvestEstimates = new HashSet<HarvestEstimate>(0);
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>(0);

    public Gmu() {
    }

    public Gmu(int gmuNbr) {
        this.gmuNbr = gmuNbr;
    }

    public Gmu(int gmuNbr, Set<HarvestEstimate> harvestEstimates, Set<Tag> tags) {
        this.gmuNbr = gmuNbr;
        this.harvestEstimates = harvestEstimates;
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "gmu_nbr", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getGmuNbr() {
        return this.gmuNbr;
    }

    public void setGmuNbr(int gmuNbr) {
        this.gmuNbr = gmuNbr;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "gmu")
    public Set<HarvestEstimate> getHarvestEstimates() {
        return this.harvestEstimates;
    }

    public void setHarvestEstimates(Set<HarvestEstimate> harvestEstimates) {
        this.harvestEstimates = harvestEstimates;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "gmu")
    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
        return this.tags;
    }

    public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    @Column(name = "region_code", nullable = true, length = 45)
    public String getRegionCode() {
        return regionCode;
    }

    public void setRegionCode(String regionCode) {
        this.regionCode = regionCode;
    }

}
```

Tag.java

```
/**
 * Tag generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag", catalog = "heroku_74dfffe65503eee")
public class Tag implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
//  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5962836863381745774L;
    private String tagCode;
    private Gmu gmu;

    private char methodCode;
    private char seasonTypeCode;
    private int seasonNbr;
    private char speciesCode;
    private char genderCode;
    private char listCode;
    private Set<DrawResult> drawResults = new HashSet<DrawResult>(0);

    public Tag() {
    }

    public Tag(String tagCode, Gmu gmu, char methodCode, char seasonTypeCode, int seasonNbr, char speciesCode,
            char genderCode, char listCode) {
        this.tagCode = tagCode;
        this.gmu = gmu;
        this.methodCode = methodCode;
        this.seasonTypeCode = seasonTypeCode;
        this.seasonNbr = seasonNbr;
        this.speciesCode = speciesCode;
        this.genderCode = genderCode;
        this.listCode = listCode;
    }

    public Tag(String tagCode, Gmu gmu, char methodCode, char seasonTypeCode, int seasonNbr, char speciesCode,
            char genderCode, char listCode, Set<DrawResult> drawResults) {
        this.tagCode = tagCode;
        this.gmu = gmu;
        this.methodCode = methodCode;
        this.seasonTypeCode = seasonTypeCode;
        this.seasonNbr = seasonNbr;
        this.speciesCode = speciesCode;
        this.genderCode = genderCode;
        this.listCode = listCode;
        this.drawResults = drawResults;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "tag_code", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getTagCode() {
        return this.tagCode;
    }

    public void setTagCode(String tagCode) {
        this.tagCode = tagCode;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "gmu_nbr", nullable = false)
    public Gmu getGmu() {
        return this.gmu;
    }

    public void setGmu(Gmu gmu) {
        this.gmu = gmu;
    }

    @Column(name = "method_code", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public char getMethodCode() {
        return this.methodCode;
    }

    public void setMethodCode(char methodCode) {
        this.methodCode = methodCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "season_type_code", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public char getSeasonTypeCode() {
        return this.seasonTypeCode;
    }

    public void setSeasonTypeCode(char seasonTypeCode) {
        this.seasonTypeCode = seasonTypeCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "season_nbr", nullable = false)
    public int getSeasonNbr() {
        return this.seasonNbr;
    }

    public void setSeasonNbr(int seasonNbr) {
        this.seasonNbr = seasonNbr;
    }

    @Column(name = "species_code", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public char getSpeciesCode() {
        return this.speciesCode;
    }

    public void setSpeciesCode(char speciesCode) {
        this.speciesCode = speciesCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "gender_code", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public char getGenderCode() {
        return this.genderCode;
    }

    public void setGenderCode(char genderCode) {
        this.genderCode = genderCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "list_code", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public char getListCode() {
        return this.listCode;
    }

    public void setListCode(char listCode) {
        this.listCode = listCode;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tag")
    public Set<DrawResult> getDrawResults() {
        return this.drawResults;
    }

    public void setDrawResults(Set<DrawResult> drawResults) {
        this.drawResults = drawResults;
    }

}
```

Any ideas? I'm relatively new to Hibernate, but I believe I understand the mappedby concept, and again, it works fine when run locally, but not deployed to Heroku.

Thanks for any insight

Comment: are you deploying to Heroku with `git push`, `heroku war:deploy`, or something else?

Comment: heroku:deploy-war, from within Eclipse

Comment: can you try `heroku:run-war` to see if you get the same error locally?

Comment: thanks @codefinger - I did not know about that functionality, and though I still don't fully understand the original error, it helped me track down some issues and get up and running